# Difference between start_nickname and start_address

Tags: uber-api

Can somebody explain me what is the difference between start_nickname and start_address in https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-post ? Maybe in form of examples? I don't know which one to use to provide street and city info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start_nickname` in POST /requests is the label used for the destination in the rider app when you create a request via the api. So please use start[latitude|longitude] or start_place_id to specify Start Location.

So if you try to request a ride with just start_nickname and start_address

```
{
    "product_id": "a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d",
    "start_nickname" : "Uber HQ",
    "start_address" : "1455 Market Street, San Francisco",
    "end_latitude": 37.795,
    "end_longitude": -122.440,
    "end_nickname" : "Embarcadero",
    "end_address" : "One Embarcadero Center, San Francisco"
}
```

you will get a response like:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "": "Both start_latitude and start_longitude or start_place_id are 
required."
},
"message": "Invalid request",
"code": "validation_failed"
}
```

In order to make a valid ride request you need to add:

```
"start_latitude": 37.776,
"start_longitude": -122.418,
```

Or  "start_place_id"  (This is the name of an Uber saved place. Only “home” or “work” is acceptable.)